# Is it possible to submit an app only for >5 iPhones?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

Itunes Connect says that I need to attach some screenshots for 3.5 screens. But due to the screen size, we do not support iPhones less than 5. Is it possible to get through this? Also, does this exclamation mark near localization settings appear there because of screenshots? Or is it another problem? Thanks![image]

Comment: Don't worry, with iOS 9 (coming this September I guess) iPhones with 3.5'' will simply not be supported anymore. Until then, make some 'Sorry'-Screen for the iPhone 4S and you're good to go.

Comment: Don't donwvote for fun - downvote for reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you submit an iPhone app it must support all types of iPhones that support the version of iOS you are targeting.

The exclamation mark just tells you there is a validation error (missing screenshots) in your English metadata.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely cannot submit apps that works only on iPhone 5 or newer. However, you can check phone model from code and show some static page saying that phone model is too old if it is the case. But I would like to suggest to you not to do so, instead make some adaptive layout (for example using size classes).

Comment: This is pure opinion, but I'd bet a lot of money doing this would end in a rejection.

Comment: @bgilham you can notice that I don't suggest doing static page on unsupported phones, but it is possible anyway. And I also think that this will not pass a review, but there is no direct mention of that in App review guidelines

Answer (score 1):

Even if you target iOS 8 only, the 4s can still run iOS 8.

That said, if the issue is just 3.5 screenshots, run it in the simulator for iPhone 4 and screenshot it. You shouldn't be eliminating millions of potential users over screenshots.